# DataTables.net custom font-size after sorting

Tags: jquery, css, sorting, datatable, datatables

I'm using [DataTables.net](https://www.datatables.net/) to insert a Table in my website. I also added a function to add/remove columns in this table. In order to fit the container size, I change the font-size in the table in respect to the column number.

**My problem**: If I use the sorting function (arrows next to the header), those changes in font-size are not considered.

**For example**: 
I have my table and add a 5. column. After this, the font-size changes to 0.8em. The I push the sorting arrow in order to sort my results. The table reloads with the original font-size 1.0em.

Is there a possibility to intercept the sorting function to insert my method to change the font-size? Or does anybody has another idea to solve that problem?

**EDIT:** I have the same problem when i change the page in order to show more results in the table.

**EDIT:** Here is the code I use to change the font-size(it works on the actual table view, but not if I change the table by sorting or changing pages). I call that method whenever a column has been added/removed.

```
 if(counter < model.getMaxCol()){
    $('#room-table tr').css('font-size', "1.0em");
 }
 else if(counter = model.getMaxCol()){  
    $('#room-table tr').css('font-size', "0.75em");
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to change the font size?

Comment: I added the code to change the font size :-)

Comment: You need to use one of the built-in datatables callback functions e.g `fnRowCallback` to apply a custom CSS class to the rows before they get rendered.  Can you post your datatables initialisation code please?

Comment: I used the callbackfunction, thank you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try adding a custom class to the row rather than just changing the font so that the sorting classes that are added are overridden as well? e.g.

```
if(counter = model.getMaxCol()){  
    $('#room-table tr').addClass('customFont');
 }
```

CSS:

```
.customFont {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

Edit: using the fnRowCallback as suggested by markpsmith

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({

  "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {

  if ( true ) // your logic here
  {
    $(nRow).addClass( 'customFont' );
  }
}

});
```

Comment: @user2550641, `fnRowCallback` is name in old notation and will be removed in future versions, use [`rowCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) instead.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com thanks for the heads up, i wasn't aware of this

Comment: In this context I have another problem now: The `rowCallback` fires normally, but my code is not performed each time. I use serverside processing and `deferRender`, maybe the function is fired before the table rows are created?