# Custom font-size after sorting: rowCallback does not work with server side processing?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm using `DataTables.net` to insert a Table in my website. I also added a function to add/remove columns in this table. In order to fit the container size, I change the font-size in the table in respect to the column number.
I find a solution how to do this with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776967/datatables-net-custom-font-size-after-sorting).

This worked perfect, but when I changed my table to be generated with server side processing (There are a lot of data to display), the `rowCallback` does fire but the class is not appended and though the font-size doesn't change. It can't be the code because it work on other situations too (for example if a column is set visible/invisible).

```
rowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    $('#table tr td').attr('class', getFontSize(counter));
    $('#table tr th').attr('class', getFontSize(counter));
},
```

Is it possible that there is a connection to the modified creation with server side processing?

Comment: since you are wanting this for the whole table, seems like it would be more efficient to toggle class on table itself rather than on each cell ... add css rule based on table class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **NOTES**

Reducing font size in order to fit table into a container is bad decision in terms of accessibility and mobile device support. Consider using [Responsive](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension or [Horizontal scroll](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html) instead.

> **SOLUTION**

You can add class to the `table` element as it is more efficient.

```
$('#example').addClass(getFontSize(counter));
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2sfL9xgf/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this also does not work for me in the `rowCallback` method of the plugin which has been my problem in the question.I don't like to use the other two options, because the adding of columns in the table is only a small addon and normally there only shoul be displayed four default columns and not more.

Comment: @user2550641, Can you share a link to your page or create an example where it doesn't work? See my jsFiddle for demonstration that setting font size for the whole table works without using `rowCallback`.

Comment: Yes you're right, it now works without using `rowCallback`. In another thread, they said I should use that callback which worked fine without server side processing but now, it seems to be better not using it.Thank you!